# php reading from file and manipulating the data

Tags: php

I am having some difficulty with reading info from a text file. Is it possible to use php and get one line at a time, and compare that line to a variable, one character at a time? Every time I add the character searching algorithm it messes up. or does the file reading only do full files/lines/character
ex:

```
    $file=fopen("text/dialogue.txt","r") or exit("unable to open dialogue file");
    if($file == true) {
        echo "File is open";
        fgets($file);
        $c = "";
        while(!feof($file)) {
            $line = fgets($file)
            while($temp = fgetc($line)) {


               $c = $c . $temp;
               //if statement and comparrison
            }

        }
    } else {
        echo "File not open";
        }
    fclose($file);
```

Comment: You are missing the semicolon here: $line = fgets($file)

Comment: fgetc function requires a handler to be passed, not a string, like you did: fgetc($line). http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetc.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use php **file** function to read a file line by line

```
<?php

   $lines = file("myfile.txt");

   foreach($lines as $line){
       ## do whatever you like here
       echo($line);
   }

?>
```

Please check php manual

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Comment: Thanks. I tried this earlier but probably did it wrong, its working with each line now, I still have to do some reading to get the rest of the way